# is it okay to freeze calamari after cooking, even though it was frozen at time of purchase?

Tags: freezing

Is is safe to freeze calamari prepared as an appetizer if it was frozen earlier at the time of purchase?

Comment: Welcome! It's absolutely okay to freeze your calamari appetizers. But can you edit your question to add more detail as to what your specific concerns are? Or does this answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

All sorts of foods that were once frozen, are thawed, cooked, and then re-frozen for storage.  There is not a safety issue here, as long as the food was thawed, cooked, cooled, and re-frozen properly.  The long-term concern is quality.  There are two issues.  First, dehydration (commonly known as freezer burn) can occur with longer term freezer storage.  Secondly, freezing and thawing often degrades the cell structure of a product, impacting it's texture.  This is often undesirable. You can see other questions on this site about packaging for, and length of time for storage in, the freezer.